# Render twig template using javascript

Tags: javascript, twig

I'm trying to get a twig template to render in javascript with no luck at all. The console is not getting me any errors and the template not getting rendered.

What am i doing wrong?

Code:

```
import Twig from 'twig';

fetch(videos).then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.items.forEach(item => {
        Twig.renderFile('./themes/mytheme/views/components/thumbnail.twig', {item:'item'}, (err, html) => {
            html; 
        });
  });
```

Comment: can you show me your rendering method ? not only `twig` part.

Comment: @Natsathorn Yes, i have edited the code.

Comment: It loads the file, i dpnt get 404 or something. but the twig itself is not getting rendered. now it only holds a p-tag with some dummy content for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure where do you using `Twig` (backend or frontend) but I think your problem is you are trying to compile `twig file` and put the compiled result into some element. I try using `twig` myself before answer you, it seems like `Twig.rendering` is not method to render. It is template file compiling method. So, `html` inside the `renderFile`s scope is the compiled result. You have to put it into element somehow. Because of `html` is string, `html;` will do nothing.

Actually, you can use `console.log(html)` to see the result of it. (It will be html string.).

Just add the method to use `html` into the scope. Then, it should works.

You need something like this inside your `renderFile`

`document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html`